# ¿Como exportar una matriz de datos?

Tags: excel, vba

Lo que necesito hacer es algo complejo así que tratare de explicarme lo mejor posible...

Resulta que tengo este formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En ese formulario el usuario primero debe seleccionar un capitulo, luego un subcapitulo y por ultimo un ítem, en cuanto selecciona el ítem automáticamente se le traen al Listbox la información de "Código" "Descripción" y "Unidad", si el quiere ver el resto de datos debe darle click al botón "Ver APU", y en ese momento el programa debe ir a la siguiente base de datos y traer los datos que voy a señalar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tomando como ejemplo que el usuario eligiera " STC base asf.-4%asf, ag.1.5" ", el programa le deberá llevar todos esos datos que están resaltados, lo mismo si hubiera elegido otro ítem (los de color rojo) se les debe llevar el rango comprendido entre un ítem y otro, pero como les dije el rango en cambiante entre un ítem y otro pueden haber 2 elementos y en otras partes 12, así que no se como llevarme el rango especifico que necesito...
Espero haberme hecho entender, cualquier información adicional con gusto se las dares.

P.D: Este es el código que uso para buscar los datos

```
If Me.cbxitm.Value = "" Or Me.cbxitm.Value = " " Then
Me.lbxAPU.Clear
Else
Me.lbxAPU.Clear
j = 1
Set Db = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("APU")
Filas = Db.Range("C2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Me.lbxAPU.RowSource = ""
For I = 2 To Filas
    If LCase(Db.Cells(I, j).Offset(0, 2).Value) Like "*" & LCase(Me.cbxitm.Value) & "*" Then
        Me.lbxAPU.AddItem Db.Cells(I, j).Offset(0, 1)
        Me.lbxAPU.List(Me.lbxAPU.ListCount - 1, 1) = Db.Cells(I, j).Offset(0, 2)
        Me.lbxAPU.List(Me.lbxAPU.ListCount - 1, 2) = Db.Cells(I, j).Offset(0, 3)
    Else
    End If
Next I
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución puede ser hacer un contador desde la celda donde comienza la referencia buscada y desde allí cuente fila a fila hasta que encuentre una nueva referencia.

Esto lo sabremos evaluando la cantidad de caracteres en el campo `[Código]` con la función `LEN`. Una vez se tenga cuantas filas son ya es fácil seleccionar los rangos que queremos.

Ejemplo de como puede funcionar:

```
Sub copyrange()

Dim i, j As Integer

j = 1 'Inicia conteo en 1 para incluir la primera fila donde la referencia inicia y la condición es igual a 7 caracteres.
For i = 1 To Filas 'i = numero de fila donde se encuentra la celda con el código de referencia buscado.
    If Len(Db.Cells(i, 2).Value) <> 7 Then 'Se evalúa si cada celda es diferente a 7 caracteres.
        j = j + 1 'si lo es entonces sume uno a nuestro contador j.
    Else
        Exit For 'Al llegar al siguiente código este tiene 7 caracteres por lo cual no sumara mas a el contador y terminara el ciclo for.
    End If
Next i

Db.Range("B" & i, "F" & j).Select 'Ya puede seleccionar el rango entre la fila i inicial hasta la fila j final entre las columnas B y F.

End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha sido de mucha ayuda